# Generate PDF of Invoice in QuickBooks Online

Tags: node.js, pdf, quickbooks-online

Hello Everyone I am using QuickBooks Online trial version.
Where I have a problem in generating PDF of invoice.

I am trying for that response of their API to convert it into Base64 and store it value in Buffer.

And also download the pdf of invoice from their site and got a response and store it into buffer, but both buffer values are different.

Here it is my code:-

```
router.get('/pdf',async function (req, res) {

var pdf = await qbfun.getPdf();
res.contentType("application/pdf");
var base64data = new Buffer(pdf, 'binary').toString('base64');
var apidata = new Buffer(base64data, 'base64');

var filePath = "/invoice212.pdf";
console.log('__dirname', __dirname)
fs.readFile(__dirname + filePath , function (err,data){
    console.log("==============================")
    console.log("From api",apidata)
    console.log("==============================")
    console.log("==============================")
    console.log("From File",data)
    console.log("==============================")
    res.send(apidata);
});
})

exports.getPdf = async function() {
var id = '212'
var url = config.api_uri + "123145873158439" + "/invoice/" + id + 
"/pdf"
console.log('Making API call to: ' + url)
var requestObj = {
url: url,
headers: {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
  'Content-Type' : 'application/pdf'
}
}

// Make API call
var result = await make_api_call (requestObj)
var data = result.body
return data;
}
```

And Result will come like this:-[Here you can see buffer values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nowYy.png)